# Django many to many relationship, use one table for Two or more model

Tags: django, many-to-many, relationship

iesi am having following table

1. **hotels** *(Model)*

   - id
   - name
2. **rooms** *(Model)*

   - id
   - name
3. **facilities** *(Model)*

   - id
   - name
4. **facility_properties**

   - facility_id
   - linking_id
   - type *(hotel or room)*

in Django i want to create a link. in both, hotel and rooms i want to use facility_properties table as many-to-many linking table.
it can be hotel and facility linking or room and facility linking. linking_id can be hotel id or room id where types define whether its hotel or room

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [`GenericForeignKey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/contenttypes/) which allows you to have a relation with any kind of model.

Translating what you require would lead to this:

```
class FacilityProperty(models.Model):
    facility = models.ForeignKey(facility, on_delete=CASCADE)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    linking_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    link_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'linking_id')
```

The `link_object` will point to either a `Hotel` or a `Room`, depending on how you use the relationship.

Here is an example:

```
h = Hotel.objects.create()
r = Room.objects.create()
f = Facility.objects.create()

prop = FacilityProperty(link_object=h, facility=f)
prop.save()

prop = FacilityProperty(link_object=r, facility=f)
prop.save()
```